How to save a dark mode on local storage?
I made a button for dark mode, but when I leave the page, it goes back to light mode. How can I save the user's choice so that when they go to another page they can continue in the mode they chose?
Js:
let trilho = document.getElementById('trilho')
let body = document.querySelector('body')

trilho.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    trilho.classList.toggle('dark')
    body.classList.toggle('dark')

})

Css:
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* DARK MODE */
.trilho {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #6e6d6d;
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trilho .indicador {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(.8);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}

.trilho.dark {
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

.trilho.dark .indicador {
    left: 38px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body.dark .container {
    background-color: #000;
}

body.dark footer {
    background-color: #000;
}

body.dark header {
    background-color: #000;
}

body.dark h1 {
    color: #fff;
}

body.dark a {
    color: #fff;
}

body.dark form{
    box-shadow: none;
}

body.dark .rodape{
    color: #fff;
}

HTML:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Website</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="darkmode.js" async></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <header>     
            <nav>        
             <ul class="nav-links">
                 <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>    
    
    
          
              <div class="menu-hamb-button hide-on-desktop">
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
            </div>
           
            </nav>   
    
            <div class="trilho" id="trilho">
                <div class="indicador"></div>
            </div>
     
        </header>
    
        <div class="container">
             <h1>Website</h1>
        </div>
        <footer>
    
        <span class="rodape">Website</span>      
        </footer>
    
    </body>
    </html>

I tried some javascript commands for local storage, but they didn't work in my html/css, maybe because the way I made my dark mode is different, I don't know.

since theme is a constant, clicking the "trilho" button will only toggle the saved setting once - until you refresh the page

Didn't you try localStorage() to make dark mode persist?

When the page loads, check the theme is set to dark. Then it applies the dark mode.
 let trilho = document.getElementById('trilho');
 let body = document.querySelector('body');

 const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
 if (theme === "dark") {
     trilho.classList.add("dark");
     body.classList.add("dark");
 }


Every time when the user toggles the button, check the body has dark class. If it does save it on the localStorage
trilho.addEventListener('click', () => {
 trilho.classList.toggle('dark');
 body.classList.toggle('dark');

 if (body.classList.contains("dark")) {
     localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
 } else {
     localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
 }
});




All of the above answers are valid. You can look into the following
The prefers-color-scheme CSS media feature is used to detect if a user has requested light or dark color themes. A user indicates their preference through an operating system setting (e.g. light or dark mode) or a user agent setting.
You can use @media to detect the user-preferred theme and apply the colors accordingly. This article provides more information.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .theme-a.adaptive {
    background: #753;
    color: #dcb;
    outline: 5px dashed #000;
  }
}




let trilho = document.getElementById('trilho');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

// Check local storage for the user's theme preference
const theme = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");

// Set the initial theme based on localStorage
if (theme === "dark") {
    body.classList.add("dark");
    trilho.classList.add("dark"); // Ensure the button reflects dark mode
} else {
    trilho.classList.remove("dark"); // Ensure the button reflects light mode
}

// Add event listener to toggle dark mode
trilho.addEventListener('click', () => {
    trilho.classList.toggle('dark');
    body.classList.toggle('dark');

    // Update localStorage with the current theme
    if (body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
        trilho.classList.add("dark"); // Dark mode button
    } else {
        window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
        trilho.classList.remove("dark"); // Light mode button
    }
});
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* DARK MODE */
.trilho {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #6e6d6d; /* Light mode background */
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trilho .indicador {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000; /* Light mode ball */
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(.8);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}

.trilho.dark {
    background-color: #c3c3c3; /* Dark mode background */
}

.trilho.dark .indicador {
    left: 38px; /* Position for dark mode */
    background-color: #fff; /* Dark mode ball */
}

body.dark .container {
    background-color: #000; /* Dark mode container */
}

body.dark footer,
body.dark header {
    background-color: #000; /* Dark mode footer and header */
}

body.dark h1,
body.dark a,
body.dark .rodape {
    color: #fff; /* Dark mode text color */
}

body.dark form {
    box-shadow: none; /* Dark mode form */
}
 <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-hamb-button hide-on-desktop">
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
                <div class="btn-line"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="trilho" id="trilho">
            <div class="indicador"></div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Website</h1>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <span class="rodape">Website</span>
    </footer>




It's working, but the buttons are reversed (when it's in dark mode, it has the light mode button, a white button, and when it's in light mode, it has the dark mode button, a dark button).

Try updated code.

In light mode, the button has a grey background and a black ball and you drag it to go to dark mode.
In dark mode, the button has a light background and a white ball and you drag it to go to light mode.
But in the code you sent me, when it's in dark mode, the button has a grey background and a black ball, and in light mode the button has a light background with a white ball. How can I fix this?

Code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain what you've actually changed to address the issue.

I have just updated the classes for both dark and light mood as i have added comments along with css

Thanks, it's perfect now!
Would you know how to make the saved mode work for all the pages on the site? Because it's saving each page manually. I wanted it to save to any page and apply to all of them at once.

Usama, the code is working perfectly, the dark mode applies to all pages automatically. I've discovered that the problem is with the browser I use, Firefox (and it forks). In other browsers (Brave, Opera) it works perfectly, but in Firefox you have to set the dark mode manually on each page, it doesn't work automatically for everyone. Do you know why this happens?

Why do you first toggle with trilho.classList.toggle('dark'); and then either add or remove a class with trilho.classList.add("dark"); resp. trilho.classList.remove("dark");?
